# The dial has been set to 10 days (future/past)

Tags: word-usage

I was watching a show and I am trying to translate it.  What will be a natural way to describe the following context:

Actually there is a door with a dial that can be set to a fixed number of days in future or in the past. Then that door takes you to that place as it would be like a few days later or as it was a few days ago.

Future (10 days)

> The dial has been set to 10 days in future.
>
> The dial has been set to future
>
> The dial has been set to 10 days later.

Past:

> The dial has been set to 10 days in past.
>
> The dial has been set to past.
>
> The dial has been set to 10 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

You would say

**Future**

> The dial has been set to 10 days in **the** future.
>
> The dial has been set to **the** future

**Past**

> The dial has been set to 10 days in **the** past
>
> The dial has been set to 10 days ago.
>
> The dial has been set to **the** past.

Comment: "The dial has been set 10 days ago." Or "The dial has been set 10 days ahead". Do these sound natural?

Comment: You can say "The dial has been set **to** 10 days ago" (sorry that wasn't clear in my post). "The dial has been set 10 days ahead" does not sound natural. You would say "The dial has been set to 10 days in the future"

Comment: And what do you think about: "The dial has been set to 10 days later".

Comment: No. You can't say that. To be honest, being a native english speaker I can't explain why. But I know that it is not grammatically correct.

Comment: Then why does "10 days ago" sound natural?

Comment: The words "ago" and "later" are not antonyms as far as I know. Therefore because one is valid, it does not mean the other must be. To be honest, as I said, I am not an expert on the reasons for English grammar. I just happen to know what sounds natural and what doesn't. I'm sorry :(

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish Note that there is no such thing as time travel in reality. Were it to be invented, and become something that some people were accustomed to, our language could (and probably would) change to accommodate it. Answers to this question only come from our *current* use of the language—one where such travel doesn't (and can't) occur. It's not clear to me that just because some things don't sound right in reality, they wouldn't sound right in that alternate reality. They are certainly *understandable*.

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish You would also not say *set to 10 days* ***earlier***, which is what ***later*** equates to. It's a relative term, and doesn't work well on its own without something to relate to. (Even an implied *today* isn't really good enough.) If *ten days* ***ago*** sounds natural, then the equivalent future term would be *ten days* ***hence*** (which sounds better to me).

Comment: @Jason Bassford "The dial has been set to 10 days on" will do?

Comment: @MvLog I can understand that in a colloquial sense. It's certainly something I can imagine somebody *saying*.

Comment: That doesn't make sense given the current usage of the English language. I agree with Jason. Colloquial English is very different to proper English. But in this context, "10 days on" wouldn't even make sense in colloquial terms.